# conditional formatting in google sheet

Tags: google-sheets

First Requirement in google sheet
how to highlight cell A1 if data enter in cell B1 and A1 is remain empty and when data enter in cell A1 its color auto reset.

Second Requirement in google sheet
when user enter data in B1 how auto highlights cells C1,D1,E1,F1 untill data also enter in all these cells

im want that when user enter data in cell B1 and cell A1 is empty its auto highlight the cell A1 and when user enter Data enter in cell B1 cell C1,D1,E1,F1 auto highlight/fill with color and when user enter data in all these cells its auto reset.

Comment: share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output

Comment: how share copy/sample

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this formula in range A1:F:

```
=(A1="")*(COUNTA($A1:$F1))
```

It checks if that specific cell is empty and if there is another value in that row. If you need to check B in particular add *($B1<>"")

Let me know if it's useful

[image]

Comment: Could you specify more? I'll give you a screenshot of what it looks like

Comment: Thanks a lot, it's very useful now im understand your screenshot it's really working @Martin